# Returning 'dataBytes' may expose an internal array

Tags: java, arrays, sonarqube

I have a getter method in one of the class:

```
  public byte[] getBytes() {
    return dataBytes;
  }
```

Sonar is giving me exception as. Ho do I fix this?

```
Returning 'dataBytes' may expose an internal array
```

Comment: Don't return an internal array... Do you understand the error? Do you understand why this might be a bad thing to do?

Comment: @BoristheSpider why it's a bad thing? sorry for asking stupid question.. just trying to learn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return a copy of the array, so any changes made to it aren't reflected in the original array. This does incur a performance and memory penalty of course, so for large arrays this can be something you need to think about.

```
return Arrays.copyOf(dataBytes, dataBytes.length);
```

Comment: NO, never allocate in a routine. Use a reuse pattern instead.

Comment: Is it going to return same exact bytearray without any difference right? Because if anything changes in the array because of this copyOf then it will cause problem so just trying to make sure.

Comment: @user5447339 the name is `copyOf`. What do you think it does?

Comment: I believe it is copying bytearray of original length and returning originalarray back

Comment: @user5447339 What would be the point of returning the original array? It returns the copy, not the original.